# Image Rotator - Diagnose Issues Javascript/Html

Tags: javascript, html

I have included the code I have been working on for quite some time. I am sure I have made many mistakes and have probably not written it in the most clean fashion. However, I just picked up coding again after a very long period of time. The code is working to some degree.

What I want it to do is display jpeg images that stay proportional, however will fit the screen of any display device. The images need to display one at a time and cycle to a new image approximately every 15 seconds.

I will be using a kiosk plugin to automatically open the webpage in full screen mode on remote devices. However, I also want to be able to view it from smart phones and tablets. 
For testing I have it cycling for a shorter amount of time.

Now the way the current code is working (as far as I can tell) is that it is continuously loading images into the webpage and not deleting the previous images. It may be deleting some images, but I need it to only have one loaded at a time. I used `screen.availHeight` & `screen.availWidth` to set the size of the images. For now I am only testing in google chrome and it is centering my images using the `align="center"` code.

Really all I am looking for help is to get the images to display one at a time without stacking on top of each other. I would like to use the code I have wrote so far, because I generally understand how it is working, however if their is a way simpler way I am all ears. I am sorry for the sloppiness of the code, but I have lines commented out while I was testing.

The following code is everything I have, you will just have to load your own images to display them. I believe the root of my issues is using `appendChild`, however `replaceChild` does not work, but that may be to my fault of not fully understanding what is going on.

If you need any more information from me I'll try to respond as quick as possible. I am sorry if I did not submit this in the correct fashion. Thank you for any help offered, I am truly a rookie coder who is learning by doing.

```
<html>

<body style=" overflow:hidden; background-color:#800000; border:none; vertical-align:middle" align="center">

<script>
var myIndex = 0;

(function myFunction() {
    var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
    var i = 0;

    while (i<7) {
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[0]);
        if (screenWidth > screenHeight) {
            if (i == 0) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide7.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide6.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide5.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide4.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 4) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide3.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 5) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide2.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else if (i == 6) {
                var i = i + 1;
                var y = document.createElement("IMG");
                y.setAttribute("src", "Slide1.JPG");
                y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
                y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(y);
            } else {
               // var i = 0;
                //var y = document.removeElement("IMG");
                //y.setAttribute("src", "Slide1.JPG");
               // y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
               // y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
               // document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[1]);
               // document.body.appendChild(y);
            }
        } else {
            var y = document.createElement("IMG");
            y.setAttribute("src", "IMG_3043.JPG");
            y.setAttribute("height", "auto");
            y.setAttribute("width", screen.availWidth);
            document.body.replaceChild(y);
        }
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > i) { myIndex = 1 }
    var y = document.createElement("IMG");
    //y.setAttribute("src", "Slide1.JPG");
    y.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    y.setAttribute("height", screen.availHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
    setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
    //var y = document.removeElement("IMG");
})();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why C# was added as a tag? There's no C# here.

Comment: You can't "C#" it anymore now though.

Comment: I had C# added as a tag, because in visual studio that is the page language that I selected for coding my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to show slide show of images, and you want to keep the image size proportional in all devices, the best thing to use is `CSS`'s [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

**Quick ref**:
[`background-image: url('YOUR_URL')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image): sets the background-image referring to your URL
[`background-position: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position): to keep the image in center of the container
[`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size): to keep the image always contained inside the container
[`background-repeat: norepeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat): so that image does not repeat in the container if single image is not able to cover up full contianer.

You can access the CSS style of an HTML element from JavaScript using, [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) where `element` will be your HTML element.

And, apology for removing so much of your code. lol.

Here is the snippet:

```js
var imgList = [
    "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-0-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-1-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-2-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-3-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-4-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-5-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-6-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-7-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-8-icon.png"
  , "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Numbers-9-icon.png"
  ],
  imgCount = imgList.length,
  currentIndex = -1,
  interval = 0.5 * 1000,   // TIME-INTERVAL 500ms
  containerSelector = "#slideContainer",
  container;

function loop() {
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgCount;

  container.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgList[currentIndex] + "')";
  console.log(currentIndex);
}

(function() {
  container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);

  setInterval(loop, interval);
  loop();
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#slideContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="slideContainer"></div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is working exactly how I envisioned it. Thank you for your help. Now I just need to figure out if I can remove the blink that occurs when it cycles images.

Comment: @Roofus that blink comes because image has not loaded/cached and it is loading the image. If the image has loaded once, then the blink wouldn't be there. Try pre-caching the image once.